# What is the origin of the Arabic word دزينة (dazina)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, arabic

As a Semitic language, one would expect the word dozen to be rooted in Aramaic (such as תריסר in Hebrew). This is obviously not the case, as the word appears similar to "dozen", rooted in Latin.
Is this indeed true? And if so, how did the Latin roots reach Arabic?

Comment: This discussion is perhaps of interest: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dozen-of-eggs.2619929/

Answer (score 3):

*dazzīna* is a modern borrowing from Italian *dozzina*. That said, there a few Latin loanwords in classical Arabic, almost all of them belonging to military vocabulary, for example the Qur’anic *ṣirāṭ* from strata “road”. (Latin was the language of the Roman army, even in the East).

Comment: Thanks! Could you refer me to a source?

Comment: Look here: https://archive.org/stream/foreignvocabular030753mbp#page/n211/mode/2up pp. 195-6.

Answer (score 1):

It is from Italian *dozzina*. It is borrowed to Turkish as *düzine*, then to Arabic.